# Using NASDAQ API, can't use decode on urlopen

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, httpresponse, urllib, decoding

I'm trying to use the NASDAQ API from https://github.com/Nasdaq/DataOnDemand but cannot seem to get it to work in Python 3.

I fixed the urllib stuff and first got an error at line 92 which I fixed by encoding it to utf-8

```
Before:
request_parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
Fix:
request_parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')
```

But now i get an error on:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>>TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

When i try to fix it by decoding i get:

```
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).decode()
 OR
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).decode('utf-8')
 >>>AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

This is what my imports look like:

```
 import urllib.request
 import urllib.parse
 import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
 import re
 from pprint import pprint
 import matplotlib.dates as mdates
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import datetime as dt
```

Any help is appreciated